# Windows client and Web client - same business tier and data tier

Tags: .net, wcf, architecture, multi-tenant, business-logic-layer

I need to write a product in .NET for my company whose frontend or UI will be different - win forms, Web and Mobile but the business logic and database will be the same.

Can anyone share or suggest the architecture which you used to achieve this in your case ? I was also considering the following.

1. write the business tier and WCF and expose them as services.
2. can I use WCF data services ?
3. should I use JSON from WCF to return large number of data ?
4. can entity framework also help here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The architecture you are suggesting is very similar to what I use all the time. You can substitute any number of web service/RESTful/WCF types of communication layers. Mix and match, use them all, find the one you like the best.  All of these are good.

Web services have been around the longest. They will have more instances of long running systems. Web services also have a transport layer around them called SOAP. It can add complexity to your client's communication with your service if your client doesn't have built in support for SOAP.

WCF is an updated version of a web service. I haven't done much with them. I do know that some of the client side frameworks have a difficult time communicating with WCF services. That was my experience. Your mileage may vary.

I am using RESTful through the Web API included in MVC. It is by far the easier method I have used to exchange data with a client application. For my application, I am using JSON as the data transport layer. I could have just as easily used XML. MVC has both built in.

There is support from just about every major player in the browser framework world to use RESTful services. My current application uses a combination of AngularJS (a Google framework) and MVC in .NET. I could also substitute KnockOut, or any of another dozen or so client side frameworks. Or write your own.

I am also using Entity Framework (EF) to facilitate the CRUD aspects of data storage in SQL Server. I could have just as easily pointed at Oracle or some other database. EF works with anything that has an ADO.NET or ODBC driver. When EF isn't sufficient for my needs, I can use the EF `DbContext` to communicate to the database via `LINQ`. And if `LINQ` can't cut it (that doesn't happen often), I can also execute SQL queries, stored procedures, etc. through the `DbContext`.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response.When you mention mvc, have you also considered winforms ? are you suggesting database, EF, wcf and then branch out to winforms  and asp.net/mvc ?

Comment: Each of them can be completely independent of the other. You could use WinForms (I have) with web services, the WebAPI, or WCF. The application I am writing could have been written completely with MVC (both the web side and the server side), but it made more sense for me to use an MVC client side framework. You have the gist of my answer based on your comment. I wouldn't use WCF personally due to how much more difficult it is to used from the client side. I would use RESTful as everything can talk to it easily.